# Best way apply key between server-client android studio

Tags: android, rest, security, connection

i am developing an android app. it's using php rest api for database process.
what is best way make it secure.

i can send and recieve datas from android studio but this means anyothers can

readed about  googleauthutil  (year 2022 and i don't know its still valid process)

if java codes in android studio could be hidden i wouldt set a key like '054ss6yTTYd545d' server side and app side,  and wouldn't need to ask this question

thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1-Encrypt data and generate always same  encryption key on run time with
your
app package name(use other key as well if not want to use package name). decrypt data in API(server side) with same key.

2- store your private key in gradle and use it to encrypt data

3- use access token on all APIs calls after login(token must be provided from server
on every login (manage session time of token))

4- use Authorizations

5- Take your base URL in Gradle file

Comment: This is pretty bad advice.  You don't need to encrypt your data in transit, that's what https is for.  And if you were to do so, you do NOT do it off of the package name.  You would generate a public and private key and do a proper key exchange.  Making a key off your app name is a HORRIBLE idea and completely insecure.  And putting your base url in a gradle file is useless for security, the only benefit you might get from that is to automate staging and prod builds to different servers.